# jquery cross fade two images

Tags: jquery, image

I'm trying to achieve a simple cross-fade on two images, however this seems jumpy and not very pleasing to the eye.  Is there any way to determine a fadeout time and make it smoother?  Currently it just ends without fading out.

Consider:

```
<div class="fadein">
<img src="#" border="0" width="964" height="49" alt="" style="display:block;margin:auto;" id="level2Menu" />
<img src="#" border="0" width="964" height="49" alt="" style="display:block;margin:auto;" id="level2Menu" />
</div>

.fadein {
overflow:hidden;
height: 49px;
}

    var $ = jQuery;
$(function () {
    var fElement = $('.fadein');

    if ( !console && !console.log ){
            console = {};
        console.log = function(){};
    }

    fElement.find('img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        if (!fElement.data('paused')) {
            fElement.find(':first-child').stop(true,true).fadeOut(1000).next('img').fadeIn(1000).end(1000).appendTo('.fadein'); //.stop(true,true) fixes le tabbed/hidden animation queue
        } else {
             console.log('waiting...');
        }
    }, 5000);
});
```

TYIA

Comment: [how's this](http://jsfiddle.net/29Sad/1/) - if you make your images positioned absolutely it will remove the jumpy effect

Comment: I see where you're going with this, but it messes up the design of my site... these images sit beneath a nav in the header

Comment: as long as the height of `.fadeIn` is the height of your images then it shouldn't mess anything up as it will still take up the same space as your banners: http://jsfiddle.net/29Sad/4/.  If you want a simple fade rotator I wrote one here: http://jsfiddle.net/gJUPT/2/

Comment: Ah I see, that seems to have done it - cheers @Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/29Sad/2/

```
.fadein img{
    position:absolute;
}
if (!fElement.data('paused')) {
            fElement.find(':first-child').stop(true,true).fadeOut(1000);
fElement.find(':first-child').next('img').fadeIn(1000).end(1000).appendTo('.fadein'); 
        }
```

Basically added position:absolute for images. And a bit of change in the js.

Comment: If you face trouble with layout, you can set the width and height for div.fadein. That way if would not disturb your layout, given that all the images are of same dimensions.

Comment: As above, absolute positioning can't really be used at it messes up the site design.  Thanks though!

Comment: @user5623896726 Not necessarily.. Absolute positioning is feature built for purpose. It doesn't harm using it properly. If all your images are of same dimensions, position absolute will not harm your layout.

http://jsfiddle.net/29Sad/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
fElement.find(':first-child').appendTo('.fadein').fadeOut(1000, function () {
    $(this).next('img').fadeIn(1000)
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/29Sad/3/)

Comment: Better, and helpful thank you.  Only problem now is, there's no real crossfade - leaves a blank area where the images did exist previously.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using the `requestAnimationFrame`, which will provide the best performance, and includes a polyfill for browsers who don't support it:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
      function( callback ){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
})();

var start = null;
var fadeFlag = true;
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    var speed = 2000;
var delay = 5000;

function step(timestamp) {
  var progress;
  var fadingIn, fadingOut;  
    fadingIn = fadeFlag ? imgs[0] : imgs[1];
    fadingOut = fadeFlag ? imgs[1] : imgs[0];

  if (start === null) start = timestamp;
  progress = timestamp - start;

  if (progress > speed) {
    if(progress > delay){
        start = null;
        fadeFlag = !fadeFlag;
    }
    else{
      fadingIn.style.opacity = progress/speed;
         fadingOut.style.opacity = progress == 0 ? 1 : 1 - progress/speed;
    }
  }
  else{
    fadingIn.style.opacity = progress/speed;
  fadingOut.style.opacity = progress == 0 ? 1 : 1 - progress/speed;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/29Sad/9/

ref: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame